# ecs error: "An error occurred (ClusterNotFoundException) when calling the..."

Tags: amazon-ecs

I've defined a cluster in ECS and failed to clean it up properly.  I've  terminated EC2 instances that are associated with this cluster which get recreated.  No clusters/repos/services appear in my ECS console.  In fact, when I go to this service through the console, I see the getting started wizard.  I've started some digging with the CLI.

When issuing the commands:

- aws ecs list-container-instances
- aws ecs list-services
- aws ecs list-tasks

I see the message **An error occurred (ClusterNotFoundException) when calling the ____ operation: Cluster not found.** (even when including my region).

When issuing the command:

- aws ecs describe-clusters

I get the result:

```
{
    "clusters": [],
    "failures": [
        {
            "arn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:123456789012:cluster/default",
            "reason": "MISSING"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any ideas on how I can clean up my mess would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The command  `aws ecs describe-clusters` only shows your default cluster.

You should write `aws ecs describe-clusters --cluster <your-cluster>` to check if it was correctly cleaned up.

Answer (score 11):

There was a CloudFormation listing this cluster in its configuration.  Even though this cluster was not visible in the ECS console, a CloudFormation stack was creating EC2 instances using the deleted cluster configuration.  The CloudFormation stack was responsible for these EC2 instances.  Deleting the stack solved this issue.

Comment: How did you delete the stack without deleting your ECS cluster? I used the wizard to set everything up and when I query clusters (using same command as above), I get the same error you get above except for a different region (that I'm not using). It responds

```{
    "clusters": [], 
    "failures": [
        {
            "reason": "MISSING", 
            "arn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:XXX:cluster/default"
        }
    ]
}```

And I'm not using resources in US-WEST-2. My cluster is in US-WEST-1.

Comment: Ooops! You need to specify the cluster to describe to get a proper return. 

```aws ecs describe-clusters --cluster CLUSTERNAME```

Answer (score 3):

I hope your cli is configured for a default region that is different than where the cluster is.
Do 'aws configure' and change the region.

Answer (score 0):

aws ecs describe-services --services  --cluster  --region

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: aws: error: argument --region: expected one argument